# Python numpy array: Index error, Index out of bounds

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

The following code is just an example of my original code which is as follows

```
batch_size = 10
target_q = np.ones((10, 1))
actions = np.ones((10, ), dtype=int)
batch_index = np.arange(batch_size, dtype=np.int32)
print(target_q[batch_index, actions])
print(target_q.shape)
```

I get the following error
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1.

Can someone please explain what this means and how to rectify it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In numpy you can index arrays of size `N` up to index `N-1` (along a given axis), otherwise you will get the IndexError you are seeing. In order to check how high can you go with an index, you can print `target_q.shape`. In your case it will tell you `(10, 1)`, which means that if you index `target_q[i, j]`, then `i` can be maximally 9 and `j` can be maximally 0.
What you do in your line `target_q[batch_index, actions]` is you insert actions as so called fancy indexing on the second position (`j`) and `actions` is full of ones. Thus, you are trying to many times index with 1, whereas the highest allowed index value is 0.
What would work would be:

```
import numpy as np

batch_size = 10
target_q = np.ones((10, 1)) 
# changed to zeros below
actions = np.zeros((10, ), dtype=int)
batch_index = np.arange(batch_size, dtype=np.int32)
print(actions)
print(target_q.shape)
print(target_q[batch_index, 0]) 
print(target_q[batch_index, actions])
```

that prints:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
(10, 1)
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it properly. So in my code, the value of actions are the numbers[31, 37, 27, 46, 45, 32, 36, 42, 37, 49] and batch index is batch_index = np.arange(batch_size, dtype=np.int32) with batch size = 10. I get the following error IndexError: index 32 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4. So how would you suggest I procced with overcoming the error?

Comment: If you find my explanation useful, then please upvote it. The second thing, is that it would be best if you asked your question with actual values you used, clear information what you are trying to achieve and what output you are expecting and the real output it produces. Then it will be easier to help.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've upvoted. My test code is for reinforcement learning. Where  target_q[batch_index, actions] = rewards + self.gamma * np.max(next_q, axis=1)*dones. The values are as follows the action is similar to the one I mentioned in the previous comment, the value of the reward is [ 10. -20. -20. -20. -20.  10. -20. -20. -20. -20.] with shape (10, ), the value of gamma is 0.99, the shape of next_q is (10, 4) and the value of dones is [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] with shape (10, ). The value of next_q is too large for me to input over here. Can you help me out with this? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you really did upvote! Are you sure you know what it means? It is an up arrow next to my answer. Clicking it would change "0" to "1" and there is still zero there!
As for your problem: it seems to me you are new to Stack Overflow, I meant that it would be good if you EDITED your original question, clearly explaining what are you expecting the code to do and what it actually does. It is one of the Stack rules, perhaps because you did not do it, someone downvoted your questions (and now you can see "-1" next to it).

Comment: I did upvote but it says that for people with less than 15 reputations, the votes get recorded but don't show up publically. Ahh ok, i'll edit the question.